# How can I use a button to change the Theme for material UI on my site? this is where I am so far

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I am going to share my current code on code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-mcnulty-6ejcx

I have attempted at creating a boolean and then using a button to change the state of that boolean which should in turn change the theme of the website. I would love some help in getting this to work and if you have any ideas on whether I should have multiple buttons for the themes I want to display or just 1 button which can cycle through more than 2 themes.

Any advice is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code on codesandbox. Instead of

```js
this.setState = { themeIs: false };
```

Because `setState` is a method, you have to write it like this

```js
this.setState((state) => ({ themeIs: !state.themeIs }));
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material-UI Swapping Theme]